# How to send PDF file data to flutter application from golang server through http

Tags: android, flutter, dart, go, http

I want to send PDF file data from my golang server to flutter application through http.

For that I have created one API which read PDF files in bytes format and then convert it into string and which are stored in golang server and send to flutter application.

Then my flutter application convert that string format data into Uint8List format to to store and view that PDF in flutter application itself.

But I am unable to view. After that I checked my download location of files and I found that all the PDF files in flutter application which I were downland to view those are blank. Only one pdf I am able to view properly because it's size is 3k and other PDF size is more than 10 kb.

Any Idea why I am not able to view all PDF files in flutter?

OR

Is there any limitation in http to send particular size of data?

To view PDF files in flutter application which I am download from my golang server.

My Golang code is as follows:

```
file, err := os.Open(filePath)
    if err != nil {
        ctx.JSON(http.StatusOK, gin.H{
            "status": false,
            "error":  err,
        })
    }
    defer file.Close()

    // Get the file size
    stat, err := file.Stat()
    if err != nil {
        ctx.JSON(http.StatusOK, gin.H{
            "status": false,
            "error":  err,
        })
    }

    // Read the file into a byte slice
    bs := make([]byte, stat.Size())
    _, err = bufio.NewReader(file).Read(bs)

    if err != nil && err != io.EOF {
        ctx.JSON(http.StatusOK, gin.H{
            "status": false,
            "error":  err,
        })
    } else {
        ctx.JSON(http.StatusOK, gin.H{
            "status":    true,
            "bytesdata": string(bs),
        })
    }
```

And flutter code is as follows:

```
final bytesdata = data['bytesdata'];
final List<int> codeUnits = bytesdata.codeUnits;
final Uint8List fileData = Uint8List.fromList(codeUnits);
var dir1 = await getExternalStorageDirectory();
if (dir1 != null) {
   File file = File("${dir1.path}/$fileNameToView");
   await file.writeAsBytes(fileData, flush: true);
   _redirectToPDFPage(file.readAsBytesSync(), fileList[index]["filename"]);
}
```

Comment: `read PDF files in bytes format and then convert it into string` Unclear. Are you base64 encoding the bytes? If yes thats a bad idea as you have 30% more bytes to transfer then.

Comment: `my flutter application convert that string format data into Uint8List format` ?? Why? If the bytes were base64 encoded you should just decode base64 to obtain the original bytes that you can save to file.

Comment: I just add my code. Can you please check it. If I am doing something wrong please correct me. @blackapps

Comment: You have not answered my questions.

Comment: OK, First I am not convert bytes into base64 just convert it into string using string(bytesData) in golang.  And in flutter to view I need Uint8List format hence convert that string into Uint8List format.

Comment: Using a string looks very wrong to me. And you should only care about viewing after having saved the bytes to file. I do not know go though.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this code may work for you**

```
package main

import (
    "io/ioutil"
    "net/http"
)

func handlePDFRequest(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    pdfData, err := ioutil.ReadFile("path/to/your/pdf/file.pdf")
    if err != nil {
        http.Error(w, "Failed to read PDF file", http.StatusInternalServerError)
        return
    }

    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/pdf")
    w.Header().Set("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"file.pdf\"")

    _, err = w.Write(pdfData)
    if err != nil {
        http.Error(w, "Failed to send PDF file", http.StatusInternalServerError)
        return
    }
}

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/pdf", handlePDFRequest)
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
}
```